# Why Ajax is sending object in Response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very simple script in php that is supose to send a request to ajax and return the string im putting in the .php file but when the request respond, it sends an object instead of the string. I dont know why this is hapening because i already have done this the same way previusly and works fine.

this is the form that send the request

```
<form method="POST" id="personForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="NameInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="NameInput">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="lNameInput">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lNameInput">
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="Send" class="btn btn-info" onclick="ajaxRequest($('#NameInput').val(), $('#lNameInput').val())" value="Send">
</form>
<hr>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

This is the script that send the ajax request

```
function ajaxRequest(name, lastn) {

   var params = {
      "name" : name,
      "lastn" : lastn
      };

      $.ajax({
        url: './process/resquestAjax.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function() {

          $('#result').html('<p>Procesando Peticion...</p>');

        },
        complete: function(completeResult) {

          $('#result').html(completeResult);

        },
        sucess: function(successResult) {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){
          alert('There was an error!: '+estado+' name-> '+error+' otro-> '+jqXHR);
          alert("Please contact support ias soon as posible...!");
        }
       }); // End Ajax Call
}
```

and the php file is just this

```
$nombre   = $_POST['name'];
$apellido = $_POST['lastname'];

echo "¡Hello! your name is : ". $nombre ." and your last name: ". $apellido;
```

I dont know why im not getting the string of that echo in the response of the ajax. it sends an object instead. I'm trying to make other project with database with this but i have the same issue.

Comment: You want to use `success` (not `sucess`) to do stuff based on the result.

Comment: If you add `dataType : text,` to the AJAX call it should fix it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - There shouldn't be any need, assuming the correct headers are being returned. (And if they aren't, they should be. :-) )

Comment: I agree @T.J.Crowder - but sometimes you just don't know what an OP might have done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You're using the `complete` callback, which receives the `jqXHR` object as its first argument.

Instead, you want to use the `success` (two `c`s, note), not `complete`, if you want to use the returned data. `success` receives the data as its first argument. (You can *also* use `complete` to remove the in-progress message, etc.)

So for instance:

```
function ajaxRequest(name, lastn) {
    var params = {
        "name" : name,
        "lastn" : lastn
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: './process/resquestAjax.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#result').html('<p>Procesando Peticion...</p>');
        },
        complete: function(completeResult) {
            // If you wanted to do something whether the request
            // succeeded or failed, you'd do it here. Otherwise,
            // remove this handler.
        },
        success: function(successResult) {
            $('#result').html(successResult);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){
            alert('There was an error!: '+estado+' name-> '+error+' otro-> '+jqXHR);
            alert("Please contact support ias soon as posible...!");
        }
    }); // End Ajax Call
}
```